# Timer is executing too many times

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem with `setInterval`. No matter what value I provide for the interval, it logs to the console with the same speed.

Here is the code I am using:

```js
var runButton = document.getElementById('run-button');

runButton.addEventListener('click', doWork, false);

function doWork ()
{
  var timer = calcbpMs;
  setInterval(function(){ console.log("Hello"); }, timer);
}

function calcbpMs ()
{
  var bpm = document.getElementById('bpm');
  var bpMs = (60000/bpm.value);
  return bpMs;
}
```

```html
<label for="bpm">BPM</label>
<input type="text" id="bpm" placeholder="Enter BPM"/>
<button id="run-button">Start</button>
```

Comment: Every time you click - you create another interval, but you don't cancel the previous one.

Comment: I made a couple of changes to your answer—instead of a picture of the HTML, I made a runnable snippet with just the relevant code, and changed the `alert` to a `console.log` to prevent alert box spamming when you run it. Normally I wouldn't alter an answer so much, and feel free to roll back, but hopefully you agree these changes make it easier for answerers to experiment with your code.

Comment: Yes, definitely. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var timer = calcbpMs;
```

That's not how you call a function in Javascript.  Try

```
var timer = calcbpMs();
```

What you ended up with was a reference to the function itself (which probably got treated as "0" when used as a number).

Comment: beat me to it :) the timer variable was being set to the function

Comment: A fresh pair of eyes never stops working. Thank you!